# How to output different results depending on when a "keyword" is entered by the user

Tags: kotlin

I'm writing a program to first take in a mix of Ints and Strings, when the user enters the word "done" the while loop terminates and the program will then sum up the numbers, count them, and provide the average, And I've gotten this part working. The problem I'm having is how to output results of 0 if the first word entered is "done". for example:

Works correctly:
input of 10 3 -1 cat 2 3 0 test 1 done 1 2
Output of total:18, count:7, average:2.57

Doesn't work:
**input of done 2 3 1 cat
Output of total:0, count:0, average:0**

```
fun main() {
    println("Lets begin..Enter you values: ")
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val nums = mutableListOf<Int>()

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        val line = scanner.nextLine()
        if (line == "done") {
            scanner.close()
            break
            }
        try {
            val num = line.toInt()
            nums.add(num)

        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            continue
        }
    }
    print(nums)
}

fun print(nums: Collection<Int>){
    println("total: ${nums.sum()}, count: ${nums.size}, average: ${BigDecimal(nums.average()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR)} ")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`average()` method on empty list returns `NaN`.
So, if you want it to be zero, you need to manually handle that case in `print` method.
Also, [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) is a more suitable class for number formatting:

```kotlin
private val df = DecimalFormat().also {
    it.roundingMode = RoundingMode.FLOOR
    it.maximumFractionDigits = 2
}

fun print(nums: Collection<Int>) {
    val average = if (nums.isEmpty()) 0.0 else nums.average()
    println("total: ${nums.sum()}, count: ${nums.size}, average: ${df.format(average)} ")
}
```

Comment: That work perfectly!. And thank you for the tip on decimal formatting I will use it.